# Building PXE image under Debian using debootstrap

Tags: debian, debootstrap

I'm trying to create a Debian PXE image under Debian bookworm amd64.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y live-boot debootstrap syslinux squashfs-tools genisoimage memtest86+
/usr/sbin/debootstrap --no-check-certificate --no-check-gpg --arch=AMD64 --variant=minbase --include=stress-ng,systemd-sysv stable chroot http://deb.debian.org/debian/
```

I get an error :

```
I: Can't verify that target arch works
E: Invalid Release file, no entry for main/binary-AMD64/Packages
```

I tried also with amd64 with another error :

```
E: Unable to execute target architecture
```